# Pass Column Names into SQL statement in dynamic way - Python- SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, dynamic, multiple-columns

```
query = ('SELECT ? from table', fields)
```

Example of 'fields' `value = name, surname, date`

I can put 'fields' in a list but I do not know how many (?) to put inside the query. Because, fields variable will include sometimes 5, sometimes 10 column names. I am trying to pass column names dynamically to the query.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Frame challenge, for all the pain of trying to set it up this way you could just SELECT * and then drop the extra columns in Python.

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL to this, and it's going to get messy, fast (most likely. This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: fields = table_rec['columns'] #I am getting column names dynamically. And based on this information, I want to use this variable in the select statement. As I wrote, I can not know how many columns will be. It depends on the table definitions. Is it clear?

Comment: You can't pass names via ? parameter markers (even if the number of ? matches). You must dynamically build the SQL query string with the names included as part of the text.

Comment: How can I do that? I have column names in a list. SELECT {column_names} from {TABLE}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A statement could be formed like so. Values will be like "(?, ?, ?, ?)" depending on the length of fields.

```py
# create a comma separated list of question marks
# then surround with parenthesis  
values = '('+', '.join(['?']*len(fields))+')'
        
query=('SELECT '+values+' from table',fields)
```

Not saying that this will work since you didn't share specifics of how you are connecting to or querying SQL Server.

Instead you could use the join str method:

```py
table_name = 'MyTable'

fields = ['col1','col2','col3']

values = ', '.join(fields)
        
statement = 'SELECT '+values+' from '+table_name

query
'SELECT col1, col2, col3 from MyTable'

query=(statement)
```

Comment: It gives error when I tried to execute query. TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.   cur.execute(query)

Comment: Please see the edited answer. I assume you are using pyodc? I don't believe you can use parameters in the way you were trying to set dynamic column names, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Edited answer is working correctly now in my code. Thanks

Comment: Please up vote any answers you find useful and mark answers as accepted if they solve your issue. Thank you.

Comment: This answer should not be upvoted because it allows for SQL injection. Please refer https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/

Comment: Very true, it all depends on where the dynamic column name inputs are being gathered in my opinion. If you are generating them yourself it may be acceptable. For SQL Server specifically, you could wrap dynamic references in QUOTENAME.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the query string

```
str1 = "SELECT "
for fieldname in fields:
    str1 = str1 + fieldname + ", "

select_query_string = str1[0:-2] + " from " +table
```

and then use that in query

```
query=(select_query_string)
```

Comment: It is working, thank you. I also want to add table name in a parametric way. I tried  select_query_string = str1[0:-2] + " from" + table  but it did not work. I could not understand why?

Comment: Make sure about having a space between command word FROM and table name